# BottomNavigationView Height is calculated as zero on Constraint Layout

Tags: android, layout

I have a simple layout with a fragment and bottom navigation. The fragment has its bottom constraint tied to the bottom navigation's top however, the bottom of the fragment stretches out to the parent's bottom.

See image: the green fab that's in the fragment is supposed to be above the navigation bottom.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to constrain the bottom of `nav_host_fragment` to the top of `nav_view`. Then also constrain the top of `nav_view` to the bottom of `nav_host_fragment`. Once you do that, update the height of `nav_host_fragment` to 0dp. That will make `nav_host_fragment` occupy all of the remaining available space.

Comment: This solution worked. It's quite odd that the default template doesn't come with these values...